# How can we bind the search text entered in a SearchView in Android via mvvmcross

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am developing an app in Xamarin Android along with MvvmCross. MvvmCross helps to bind view properties in layout directly to ViewModels. For EditText, we can bind the text like

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxBind="Text Property" />
```

I need to bind SearchView text using MvvmCross. I tried `Text` like below but it doesn't work.

```
<SearchView     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:queryHint="Customer name" 
    local:MvxBind="Text SearchString" />
```

**How Is it possible to bind SearchView text using MvvmCross?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `SearchView` you need to use the [`Query`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L177) property:

```
<SearchView     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:queryHint="Customer name" 
    local:MvxBind="Query SearchString" />
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The link you attached also covers all the other binding stuff which will be useful in future too :-)